# Zero Article of Countable Noun (e.g. government)

Tags: articles, zero-article

I would like to know when I can omit "the" for a countable noun.

> I've come to realized once again how many accomplishments we can make when businesses and government work together.

Here, government is a general government, so the group of people I guess.

But in dictionaries, government is a countable noun when it means " the group of people who govern a country or state", and when used as an uncountable noun, it means a system or a process of governing ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/government), for which I don't believe I am looking for in this sentence.

When can I omit the/a for a countable noun?

*I would like to ask for opinions of native English speakers.

Comment: Where did you see this sentence. I would have used "the government".

Comment: @Cardinal It's a speech of President of Korea. My American friends said it is okay so I was curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Countable nouns can refer to one thing (singular) or to two or more things (plural). Uncountable nouns are neither singular nor plural; they refer to things that cannot be numbered, such as abstract concepts, fields of study, games or sports, gases, liquids, materials, and particles or grains.

Certain nouns (like meat, stone, style, and time) can be countable or uncountable depending on the context.

- She drank **a glass** of water. (Countable)
- The window is made of **glass**. (Uncountable)

If the noun is countable, you must determine whether it is specific or non-specific. (See below.)

If the noun is uncountable, do not use an article.

- There is a lot of **sand** on the floor.
- Every winter, I give **clothing** to the poor.

[source](https://sass.uottawa.ca/sites/sass.uottawa.ca/files/awhc-articles.pdf)

---

*[government](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/government)* in the sentence is used as **general** and **uncountable** meaning *"the system used for controlling a country, city, or group of people"*; therefore, there is no need of any article.